# What detail should I be looking for in Leonard in Memento to determine the plot?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, memento

I have watched Christopher Nolan's Memento more than once and I still can't get the real thing that happened. Yes I get that the movie is shown backwards, but it really confuses me.

I understand that Leonard Shelby has amnesia which makes him unable to keep new memories. What is the key detail in Mr. Shelby that I should be looking for to understand the [ending scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqW9fnkhqrs)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need keys. We need to help Teddy to find his keys! :-)

Joke aside, you should give  attention to what Teddy says directly before the linked video.

> Teddy: "So you lie to yourself to be happy."

and later:

> Teddy: "Yeah I guess I can only make you remember the things you want to be true. Like Jimmy down there."
>
> Leonard: "He's not the right guy."
>
> Teddy: "He was to you. You got your revenge. Enjoy it while you still remember."

and sometimes later (that's in the linked video) Leonard is thinking:

> "Do I lie to myself to be happy? In your case, Teddy, yes I will."

as he is writing down Teddy's license plate to form a new clue tattoo.

Also take notice of the memory of his wife in the scene where he is driving to the tattoo parlor--especially note the chest.

> On his chest is tattoed "I've done it." while is wife is alive.

So, what do we make out of all this?

> Everyone is using Leonard - including himself. He fudges his informations to stay on a constant path of Revenge. That is the thing that makes him happy. Probably it's because he killed his wife with an overdose of insulin, a story he attributed to Sammy Jenkins. He can't stand that, he needs to see "Johnny G." as the guilty for the death of his wife, although she survived the assault and rape (as his memory in the car-drive-scene shows).

Comment: It's true that Leonard has memory of wife touching his "I've done it" tattoo... but he had that memory after Teddy suggested it to him. And the only time he has that tattoo is in that memory... at other times in the movie when he has his shirt off, the "I've done it" tattoo is not there, suggesting he never really had it.

Comment: Interesting point. Ted induced this memory-flash. That is apossible interpretation. But to the last point: I think it is possible to remove tatoos.

Comment: its not a memory because the tattoo says *murdered* my wife so she wouldn't be there with him

Comment: Is the last paragraph really a quote (if yes, what’s the source?), or your own?

Answer (score 10):

If you notice carefully (I had to pause the DVD for this) - for a fraction of a second, there is a scene in which Sammy Jenkins is sitting in a chair and for just a fraction, he turns into Leonard.

<sup>(see at 0:25)</sup>

A more detailed explanation is [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/tdnh8/there_is_an_easter_egg_in_christopher_nolans/).

Answer (score 4):

Leonard is Sammy Jenkis - or is he?

That's the point.

Much like the end of Inception - we never see the top stop spinning - so is Cobb still dreaming?

Comment: Well, in contrast to Inception, we definitely know that Leonard is Sammy Jenkins. What could make you believe he isn't?

Comment: It's never explicitly stated that he is.  You assume he is but it's not bullet proof.

Comment: @Jack, hmm, there is a direct hint in the scene where you see Sammy Jankis  in the clinic. Someone walks between Sammy and camera and then you can see a short glimpse of Leonard sitting in the place of Sammy.

Comment: @JackMarchetti  It's not bullet-proof, but *much* more likely. There is a difference between ambiguity and implication. It's just a question of probablities given all the information from the movie and the ambiguity in *Inception* is much more balanced, while all the information from *Memento* really speaks for itself. Even if the facts may not be sufficient and there might be a very tiny chance that *Teddy* is a liar and *Leonard* is not *Sammy Jenkins*, that would be based merely on blind assumption, ignoring the information given in the movie.

Answer (score 0):

I think he at least planned on getting the I've Done It tattoo to remind himself once he had finally killed "john G".  If you remember the photo Teddy shows him where he is smiling after getting his revenge, he is pointing to that area of his chest.

For those saying he got the tattoo removed, it would make sense that he get the Murdered part out of the John G Raped and Murdered My Wife Tattoo as well.

Comment: I personally wouldn't consider that the **key detail**.