# Was Leonard Shelby really crazy?

Tags: plot-explanation, memento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What detail should I be looking for in Leonard in Memento to determine the plot?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/237/what-detail-should-i-be-looking-for-in-leonard-in-memento-to-determine-the-plot)

From what I understood after watching [Memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_%28film%29#Plot), Leonard got the no of the car of Teddy and forgot where did he get it from and continued investigating with it. He noted the no just because Teddy told him his name also stands for Johnny G. But Teddy informed him that **Leonard had already killed the killer**, but he disbelieved him. Leonard had also jot down "Don't believe in his lies" under Teddy's picture because Teddy accepted not telling Leonard intentionally the truth that Teddy himself was a police officer working undercover. Later he also forgot why he wrote this for Teddy before killing him.

So what is true?

**Leonard was really crazy who gave purpose to his own life for living by investigating already settled case of rape and murder of his wife?**

Or,

**Teddy was really his wife's killer?**

Comment: Check out similar question. I think first answer covers your question as well: http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/422/564

Comment: @defaultlocale, looks like I missed the Q. I would now request the mods to close the Q.

Comment: AFAIK, users here are able to delte their own question (am I right?). So if you think that your question is already answered you don't really need mods

Comment: No I don't want to delete the question because I think closed questions can be helpful for future visitors( I am sure this question would be helpful). Anyways, I have flagged it already. :)